# jquery datatables - how to treat spaces as thousand separators?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a table that has thousands separators as spaces in one column, and I need to be able to sort the table over this (and only this) particular column.

I saw the docs suggesting `{thousands: " "}` option but this does not seem to work.

Fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/dpmL00wd/2/

What's the proper way of defining a thousand separator?

Answer (score 1):

`language.thousands` is for output only. The correct option is [**`language.decimal`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.decimal) which is used to adjust dataTables sorting algorithm. However, setting decimal to `' '` seems to be ignored, i.e the default value is empty `''` which falls back to a dot.  Apparently `' '` is recognized as `''`.

What about returning the correct number when the table wants to filter or order?

```
{ targets: [0], 
  orderable: true,
  render: function(data, type) {
    if (type != 'display') {
      return parseInt(data.replace(' ', ''))
    }
    return data
  }
},
```

The above will return `2300` as number when the column is sorted / ordered but still show `2 300` in the column.

updated fiddle -> **https://jsfiddle.net/dpmL00wd/4/**

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "numeric-comma-pre": function ( a ) {
        var x = a.replace( /\s/, "" );
        return parseFloat( x );
    },

    "numeric-comma-asc": function ( a, b ) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },

    "numeric-comma-desc": function ( a, b ) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
} );
$(document).ready(function (){
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            columnDefs: [

        {type: 'numeric-comma', targets: [0], orderable: true},
            { targets: '_all', orderable: false }
        ],
        language: {
            thousands: ' '
        }
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dpmL00wd/5/